# .NETStandard NuGet packages

Tags: c#

I am trying to download a package that will allow me to encrypt and decrypt passwords. However, I can not find a package that is compatible with my project as I am working in .NETStandard.
[image]

Is there a way to make a package that is not fully compatible still work?
When I try to change my project to a .NETFramework I do not get the option of any .NETFrameworks...
[image]

Despite another project in the same solution being targeted to .NETFramework v4.6.1

[image]

**Solutions:**

Are there any .NETStandard password encryption packages?

Is there a way to search for .NETStandard compatiable packages?

Can I make my project target a .NETFramework even though it is not an option, but is downloaded?

Comment: Uh...what kind of passwords are you encrypting?

Comment: Uh... Why would you want to decrypt passwords?

Comment: Uh... to create a login form

Comment: Asking for recommendation (packages) is off-topic. You cannot change target frameworks freely, as different project types have their own options, https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff

Answer (score 0):

The warning itself is just a warning but the library might still work fully well, especially when you are actually targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 with your project.

Basically when you create a .NET Standard library, it targets a specific version of .NET Standard and you can imagine .NET Standard as a set of interfaces a platform that supports that version of .NET Standard must support. In this case, if you are targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 with the app, the .NET Standard library will run on .NET Framework 4.6.1 anyway, so there shouldn't be any problem.

Problems could occur if you built another client targeting a different implementation of .NET like .NET Core or Mono, which wouldn't support some of the APIs that the library is using internally. In such case the application would crash once such API was accessed because the platform does not offer any implementation of it.

In case you don't require cross-platform support, you could just use classic .NET Framework library, instead of .NET Standard and the warning would disappear.

Comment: Yes, I have just updated my answer with this point. However, you may still use a library targeting full .NET if it does not do anything "malicious" - meaning it does not access any non-Standard APIs. If you can be sure of that, the library will have no issues running against any other .NET implementation supporting the same .NET Standard version.

Comment: The package does not work unfortunately - Eramake.eCryptography.

Comment: Even when you target the same .NET Framework version as the package itself?

Answer (score 0):

I'm personally using `RSACryptoServiceProvider`
from `System.Security.Cryptography`. This is available in .NET standard. Doesn't need any nuget packages either.

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
```

Edit:

I should add to this that encrypting/decrypting password is never a good idea. Password should be stored as a hash width a strong one way hasing algorithm and should never be encrypted for decryption for later use.